# How to implement a message propagation block for label-relation (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a network architecture to classify fashion images I found in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09445.pdf using keras + tensorflow (like the authors in the paper).

The paper proposes an interesting method by which not only the visual information of the images is used for classification, but also the relationships among labels are utilized. This is done using a so called "message propagation block". Since the authors are unfortunately unable to provide the code, I am trying to build it myself. However, I find myself having trouble implementing the message propagation block of the model.

The architecture of this message propagation block is outlined fairly detailed in the paper (Figure 6 + 7).

As such, I am trying to use the keras functional API to replicate this model following all the details highlighted by the authors. The paper says the model should have 46.915.690 trainable parameters, however my model has only 39,981,162 parameters.

Now I am trying to find my mistake. Since I am fairly new to the usage of the functional API, I wonder if my model implementation is technically correct or if I am missing something obvious (i.e. did some serious mistakes).

This is my entire code including the message propagation block (see comment in the code):

```
img_width, img_height = 224, 224
img_input = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

resnet50 = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=img_input, pooling=None)

x = resnet50.output

xcat_input = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name="xcat_input")(x)
xsubcat_input = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name="xsubcat_input")(x)
xattribute_input = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name="xattribute_input")(x)

reg = regularizers.l2(0.0005 )


#### message propagation block starts here (Figure 6+7 in the paper)

#################
# Top-down pass #
#################

# Category-Block
dense_category_output_blue = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(xcat_input)

# Subcategory-Block
a_minusone = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(dense_category_output_blue)
a = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(xsubcat_input)
dense_subcategory_output_blue = keras.layers.concatenate([a_minusone, a])

# Attribute-Block
a_minusone = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(dense_category_output_blue)
a = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(xattribute_input)
dense_attribute_output_blue = keras.layers.concatenate([a_minusone, a])



##################
# Bottom-up pass #
##################

# Attribute-Block
dense_attribute_output_green = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(xattribute_input)

# Subcategory-Block
dense_subcategory_output_green = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(xsubcat_input)

# Category-Block
dense_category_up = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(xcat_input)
x_category_output_green = Dense(1024, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=reg)(keras.layers.concatenate([dense_attribute_output_green, dense_subcategory_output_green]))

#### merging the result of each direction from the first part of the message passing
add1 = keras.layers.concatenate([dense_category_output_blue, x_category_output_green])
add1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None)(add1)
dense_category_output = Dense(64, activation='softmax', name='dense_category_output')(add1)

add2 = keras.layers.concatenate([dense_subcategory_output_blue, dense_subcategory_output_green])
add2 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None)(add2)
dense_subcategory_output = Dense(95, activation='softmax', name='dense_subcategory_output')(add2)

add3 = keras.layers.concatenate([dense_attribute_output_blue, dense_attribute_output_green])
add3 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None)(add3)
dense_attribute_output = Dense(75, activation='sigmoid', name='dense_attribute_output')(add3)


model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=[dense_category_output, dense_subcategory_output, dense_attribute_output])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would be quite impressed if anybody could match the exact parameter count of this fairly complex model from the paper description. I would not treat this as a high fidelity indicator of correctness. It is also pretty hard for anybody (except authors, whom you should probably contact) to just read the code and say if it is correct. You should just train it and see how it performs.

Comment: @iga thx for your comment! Since this is my first try on implementing a paper I did not know that it would be "impressive" to match the parameters, so this gives me hope of getting this to work anyways :) I did contact the authors, unfortunately they are unable to provide the code. Since the authors used keras + tf I thought it should be easy to implement it, but the message propagation part really gives me headaches...my current code is more or less my best guess regarding their schematics in the paper, but maybe someone more experienced with keras will be able to tell whether it is correct.